# retrieve array in jquery $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, http-post

I have a problem browsing elements of my forms and posting them as "JSON". I manage to recover everything except some elements like the names of people for example, which are dynamic.

I actually choose a number of names to give, and I would like to get what I have in my array of name.

here is my code :

```
<script>
    parseInt($('#id').html());
    console.log(parseInt($('#id').html()));
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_nWBzhwnk9WLgDk5EHjr3JTuZ',
    image: 'http://localhost:8000/images/default.png',
    color: 'white',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
        var myData = {
            token: token.id,
            email: token.email,
            amount: Math.round($("#result").text()),
            description: '',
            currency: 'eur',
            event: parseInt($('#id').html()),
            nb_tickets : $('#nb_ticket').text(),
            name: [],
    };
    /* 
     Make an AJAX post request using JQuery,
     change the first parameter to your charge script
    */
    $('body').Wload({text:'Paiement en cours'}); 
    console.log(myData);
    $.post("/checkout/"+parseInt($('#id').html()), myData,
        function(data) {            
        // if you get some results back update results
        $("#myForm").hide();        
        // for demonstration purposes, loop through everything in myData
        })
        .done(function () {
            $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
                modalClose: false,
            });
            $('body').Wload('hide', {time: 0});
        })
        .fail(function() {
        // if things fail, tell us
        $(".results").html("I'm sorry something went wrong");
         })
        }
    });
```

depending on the number of tickets I choose I can have several names.

in my form the ID of the names is as follows if I choose 2 tickets:

```
<input type="text" id="commande_achats_0_name" name="commande[achats][0][name]" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
```

and :

```
<input type="text" id="commande_achats_1_name" name="commande[achats][1][name]" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
```

I need to recover everything in `commande_achats_0_name` and `commande_achats_1_name` according to the number of tickets chosen..

I'm stuck on it .. if anyone could help me please

Thank you